# Is the inverse Collatz graph symmetric?

Tags: graph-theory, collatz-conjecture

Maybe a stupid question, but I couldn't find a direct answer.
When looking at this beautiful visualization of the graph of inverse Collatz sequence:

https://www.jasondavies.com/collatz-graph/[Collatz graph](https://www.jasondavies.com/collatz-graph/)

one immediately see that the graph is symmetric around the central node, each branch having a counterpart opposite from the central node.
[image]
So I am wondering, is this just an illusion and it eventually breaks down? From what I know about the Collatz sequence I was definitely expecting some more random branching.

Thanks.

Comment: This always happens, since given any even $3k+1$, there are two numbers that map to that even, and their sequences behave identically.

Comment: @DonThousand Ok. I think I mostly understand, but it still surprises me little bit that even the length of "even" sequences are "symmetric"  - 853, 1706, 3412 vs 5461,10922, 21844. (both length 3 before it branches again).

Comment: Ok. It actually does indeed seem to be only an illusion. The branch 11,22 branches after 22 into 7 and 44, while the opposite symmetric branch 75, 150, 300, 600, 1200 does not branch.  Which, nevertheless, seems to be the only exception in that graph (as far as I noticed). Very interesting still:)

Comment: any number divisible by 3 won't branch further.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/288807/a-problem-involving-the-inverse-collatz-map/289157#289157

Comment: A beautiful arrangement. If one could only apply some more 3 D rendering... :-)  Or have it as a woolen stitched picture for the wall - this would be  a nice present for christmas. Or so...